# When should a kid have memorized the multiplication table?

Tags: primary-education, multiplication-table

To contextualize: I know someone who is ten years old, and needed to use repeated addition to compute $4 \times 8$, i.e., needed to calculate it as $4 \times 8 = 8+8+8+8$.

> **Question:** By what age should a kid have memorized the multiplication table?

Comment: This is impossible to answer in my opinion.  Do you mean when does someone understand that or is able to recall the fact?  I know students that understand but struggle to recall.

Comment: Can the 10 year old quickly add the 4 eights, or does s/he struggle with adding the 4 eights?  I think that makes a difference in whether you have a cause for concern.

Comment: Preferably never... your calculator (today phone) does arithmetic faster and more accurately.

Comment: @AmyB It takes her a time to adding eights.

Comment: I'm 49 years old, have a PhD in physics, and teach math and physics for a living. When I need to know 4x9, I do it as 18+18. I don't have it memorized that it's 36. I've done it this way since I was a kid, and I do it very quickly. Why is this a problem?

Comment: Based upon what I know and see, I would say that kids should be aware of have an understanding of the multiplication table before age 7, and should have it memorized before age 8.

Comment: I guess it's better to avoid any memorizing in math as much as possible, including multiplication table. You can try to remember some pretty results like $6\cdot 6=36$ or $5\cdot 5=25$ and work your way through it if needed. However, if you're not going to compete in the 'fastest exercise solver' contest, there's no point to abuse ones memory (in case you don't want him\her to abandon math forever after the school is done).

Comment: For what it's worth, I didn't know about 30% of the multiplication table until towards the end of the 5th grade in spring 1970 when I was 12 years old. Interestingly, I think this, along with some lesser difficulties in remembering addition rules (i.e. $5+8=13)$ helped me in learning how to devise shortcuts (didn't know $8 \times 9,$ but I knew all the squares, so I'd add $8$ to $64,$ which I did by adding $10$ and then subtracting $2;$ or subtract $8$ from $8 \times 10),$ which was a useful skill in higher math (e.g. real analysis, sometimes add $0$ by adding and subtracting the same thing).

Comment: user2057368: On what are you basing this answer?

Comment: @BenjaminDickman well, first of all it's useless — if you really want to memorize something, it's better to save place for various theorems or interesting results, not just pointless facts you can re-derive every time you need them.

Second — most of people who hate math don't like it just because you have to remeber lots of stuff which isn't obvious (unless it's properly explained) and just seems excessive. But hey, if you wan't to make sure that the kid will try to forget everything you force him to learn as he has the chance to — go ahead with memorizing.

Comment: When I grew up it was second grade.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As an example of one curriculum, the Common Core standards say that students, "By the end of Grade 3, know from memory all products of two one-digit numbers." (http://www.corestandards.org/Math/Content/3/OA/C/7/) This matches my personal experience, too, for what it's worth, in the 1970's. In the U.S., this would be around age 8 or 9 years old.

Now, as someone who teaches community college remedial math, I'll note that in practice there are large cohorts of any age who have not actually memorized the times tables (age 18, 20, 30, etc.). This skill is taken as the fundamental prerequisite for our lowest-level arithmetic courses. As an informal observation, people who think that times table memorization is optional likely aren't involved in teaching algebra or higher-level subjects (including work with fractions, factoring, etc.). Students who haven't memorized the times tables are close to helpless when they get to one of our algebra classes.

To support my students in college remediation I established a website with timed quizzes, having times tables as the first and most fundamental skill. For some students it's the first occasion that they've been made aware that automaticity in "knowing times tables" is *not* the same as "being able to repeatedly add". See: http://www.automatic-algebra.org/

Comment: For common core, curious why you didn't just link to the source article [Operations & Algebraic Thinking] (http://www.corestandards.org/Math/Content/3/OA/C/7/)

Comment: I have to say my experience is different. I teach many a student who is not "close to helpless" in algebra even though they don't know all their times tables. The student who knows many of them and can get to the others is usually very successful. Also, your order of ops activity in the automatic algebra quiz sometimes marks wrong an order that will actually still produce the correct result. (Though in general I like the tool you've made.)

Comment: @DavidButlerUofA The order of operations has has been pretty thoroughly tested for over a year now, so I'd be pretty skeptical of that. Do you have an example that you think is incorrect? If you want to take it offline (and I'd be interested) email me dcollins at superdan dot net. Thanks for checking it!

Comment: Email sent, @DanielR.Collins

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Is the knowledge of the older cohorts representative? I feel like I probably used to know times tables at some point but these days I probably don't know them anymore as I usually find myself using subtraction or addition tricks for computing some multiples (7x8, 6x7, 6x8, 8x8 are the biggest offenders but some multiples of 3 and 4 also crop up I think). At the same time I've done decently well in mathematics having gotten a MA in mathematics specialized in set theory and another one in algebra.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: I just made the edit you suggested a while back.

Comment: I was about to mark my calendar to acknowledge this in the summer of 2020. But reconsidered .

Comment: Moral plus one, Danman.  Personally, I am right end of the curve in math and have a few stops in my table which I stop and think about.  BUT, I don't think this is a good rationale for kids not learning it. For one thing, extrapolating from math superstars to general population is risky.  Also, I don't think it helps me to have those glitches or would be that hard to change.

Answer (score 11):

I hope I can contribute an answer with a story.  I failed one grading period in 3rd grade math because I stubbornly refused to memorize the multiplication tables.  At that age I understood that multiplication was explained as repetitive addition. My reasoning was "why memorize that which I can derive?"

I failed because quizzes were timed, and I couldn't complete the repetitive addition fast enough.  My teacher could see what I was doing, since the I did the addition in the margins.  It still amazes me that she never pulled me aside and explained WHY memorization was important.

Why is memorization important?  I can still only think of two related reasons: (1) It's needed for the fluency required for higher math; and (2) division (and other kinds of factoring) requires the immediate recognition afforded by memorization.

So when should students memorize multiplication tables?
 1. After they have mastered addition. 
 2. Before they are introduced to division.

Comment: This was added as an anonymous suggested edit which got rejeced: " So, to answer the question: What age? Whatever ages are in 3rd grade.

I think it would be good to find out why this student is using repetitive addition. If it's because s/he didn't do homework and is falling back to addition as plan B, that's one thing. But if it's because the student wants to understand concepts rather than mindlessly applying rote memorization, they should get an atta-boy. . . But then be redirected to memorize anyway. "

Comment: I see this sometimes (marginal sequential additions) among my remedial college students. But let me one-up that: at least once I've seen someone who had to make _individual tally marks_ in order to find 8×9.

Comment: @Daniel R. Collins: I just saw your comment here as I was glancing over some threads that I gave links to in a comment to [this Mathematics Stack Exchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3579656/13130) (although I surely saw it back when you made the comment), and felt I have to mention something that came up recently in a part-time job I have. I was examining a written standardized test booklet for someone, and at one point the student had to multiply $1.36$ and $10.$ The student wrote $1.36 \times 10$ in the usual vertical column format for hand-multiplication, **(continued)**

Comment: with a horizontal answer bar drawn under it, and a question mark was written under the horizontal bar. I suppose the student forgot how to carry out the multiplication algorithm. It might have been the presence of $0$ in the units place of $10$ that caused the trouble ($1.36$ was written above $10),$ or maybe the student wouldn't have known what to do no matter what the units digit of the bottom number was. Anyway, off to the side of this the student wrote a tall vertical column of ten $1.36$'s, and then proceeded to add all of them. **(continued)**

Comment: I could see $0$ put at the bottom in the units digit spot and a tiny $6$ being carried to the top of the tens column (from adding $6$ ten times), then a $6$ put at the bottom in the tens digit spot and a tiny $3$ being carried to the top of the hundreds column (from adding $3$ ten times, after which $6$ is added), with the full answer $13.60$ written at the bottom!

Comment: @DaveLRenfro: Holy smoke, thanks for sharing that! Similarly: (a) in our lowest-level remedial arithmetic class, it's pretty common for students to express no awareness of how multiplying by 10 or powers thereof work; (b) same class, student multiplies $42 \times 12$ and comes up with $54$, I can't help but laugh, she re-does it carefully and gets the same thing again (in the add step there's a "0" in a carry which she thought didn't count for anything and didn't write down).

Comment: @Daniel R. Collins: To be honest, despite the absence of some (extremely) basic arithmetic knowledge, the student (both here and elsewhere) exhibited much more actual mathematical thought than many other students whose work I reviewed (although none of the students I'm talking about are anywhere near the top half).

Answer (score 7):

Age is not a good marker of mathematical ability as abilities can differ so much.  In addition I'd add that having a good memory obviously an advantage in the mathematical  development of a child but it is not a prerequisite nor a guarantee of success.

On to 'knowing' your times tables.  It is tempting to say that someone that recalls $8\times 4 = 32$ knows that times table but the reality is more complex.  A child that knows their times tables should be able to answer questions like, " Which times table is $32$ , $56$ and $96$ in? "  Could there be more than one? Why is $8\times 4=2\times 16$ ? There are other examples but the point is that recalling the facts isn't enough to 'know' them.

To be clear recalling multiplication  facts is an integral part of future development but caution is required or frustration can set in.

Comment: I have a masters in Mathematics and I can't answer that first question. Or rather not without factorization or thinking for quite a while. As to the the second question I'm not even sure what the correct answer would be. Pointing out both are the same power of 2? Computing their "value"?

Comment: @DRF: Re the second question: You have failed to see it because it is too obvious.  Some students don't realize that you can "move" factors between the multiplicand and the multiplier without changing the value of the product, because they conceptualize multiplication as a black box that just takes two numbers and spits out a different number according to a memorized "times table."  They don't think of it as a semantically meaningful operation over the ring of integers.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of this question might be found in the question: "When are multiplications used in primary education?", and for answering that question, let's have a look at following example: the multiplication of numbers containing multiple digits, like in this example: 789*567.

We are performing this multiplication as follows:

```
9*7=63
80*7=560
700*7=4900
=> result 5523
9*6(0) = 54(0)
80*6(0) = 480(0)
700*6(0) = 4200(0)
=> result 47340
9*5(00) = 45(00)
80*5(00) = 400(00)
700*5(00) = 3500(00)
=> result 394500
Add everything : 5523 + 47340 + 394500
3 => result 3
80+40 = 120
600+300+500 = 1400
5000+7000+4000 = 16000
40000+90000 = 130000
300000 = 300000
=> result =  447363
```

Total amount of calculations (how many times did we calculate (add, multiply, ...) something?):

```
9 multiplications
6 additions
=> 15 calculations
```

Now do the same but replacing a*b by a+a+...+a (b times)

```
9*7 = 9+9+9+9+9+9+9 = 63
80*7=80+80+80+80+80+80+80 = 560
700*7=700+700+700+700+700+700+700 = 4900
=> result 5523
9*6(0) <- 9+9+9+9+9+9  = 54, add a (0) = 540
80*6(0) <- 80+80+80+80+80+80 = 480, add a (0) = 4800
700*6(0) <- 700+700+700+700+700+700 = 4200, add a (0) = 42000
=> result 47340
9*5(00) <- 9+9+9+9+9 = 45, add two (0) = 4500
80*5(00) <- 80+80+80+80+80 = 400, add two (0) = 40000
700*5(00) <- 700+700+700+700+700 = 3500, add two (0) = 350000
=> result 394500
Add everything : 5523 + 47340 + 394500
3 => result 3
80+40 = 120
600+300+500 = 1400
5000+7000+4000 = 16000
40000+90000 = 130000
300000 = 300000
=> result =  447363
```

Total amount of calculations (how many times did we calculate (add, multiply, ...) something?):

```
0 multiplications
53 additions
=> 53 calculations
```

In other words, in case the kik doesn't know the multiplications by heart, (s)he will need to do 3 times the amount of calculations, just for multiplying two numbers of three digits. This, in its term, will ensure that (s)he will need 3 times more time for finishing his/her homework, tests and exams, leading to disappointing school results.

I guess this simple example clearly shows that, once the kid will need to multiply numbers of at least three digits, (s)he needs to know the multiplication tables by heart.

Good luck

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is not **why** one should memorization multiplication tables, but **when**.

Comment: The *when* explains the *why*: at the moment that the kid will learn to do multiplications of numbers, containing different digits, he'll need to be able to know the multiplication tables by heart. The exact age might differ from country to country, so this exact number is impossible to state.

Comment: Maybe you could [edit] your question to include the content of you comment; possibly somewhat towards the start to avoid the misunderstanding. (Possibly the when and why are interchanged.)

Comment: Thanks, @quid, I just followed your advise.